# Agregar permiso a un .log en la carpeta del programa

Tags: c#, archivo, permisos

Se puede agregar permisos a un archivo especifico desde c#, me explico, tengo un aplicación para escritorio desarrollada con c#, la app me funciona correctamente, pero cuando la inslato y el .log me queda en la carpeta del programa(la cual esta en c:/archivos de programa /miapp/) no me deja modificar el archivo .log porque no tengo los permisos, alguien sabe como puedo modificar esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde windows XP, el sistema operativo protege el contenido de la carpeta archivos de programa, lo recomendable en este caso es poner el log en una carpeta de trabajo del usuario o de windows si quiere que sea visible a todos los usuarios.

Revisa la documentacion de "Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData"

En este link del foro MSDN hay una pregunta similar:
[Donde guardar archivos en app c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/53a0cef4-ec2f-4a33-b8d4-05d797f3f782/donde-guardar-archivos-en-app-c?forum=vcses)